# PHP count Cookies

Tags: php

Как посчитать сколько раз зашел посетитель на сайт с помощью Cookies

Comment: Ахахахахаха. Перевод пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1):

Наивный, но, вроде бы, жизнеспособный вариант:

```
// Время «жизни» «посещения».
// Отсутствие активности в течение этого времени будет считаться как новое посещение.
define("VISIT_LIFETIME", 3600);

// Получаем значения из cookies, обрабатывая их отсутствие.
$visit_count = @intval($_COOKIES["visit_count"]) ?: 0;
$visit_current = @intval($_COOKIES['visit_current']) ?: 0;
$now = time();
$visit_duration = $now - $visit_current;
if ($visit_count < 1 || $visit_duration > VISIT_LIFETIME) {
    // Новое посещение
    $visit_count = max($visit_count + 1, 1);
    setcookie("visit_current", $now, $now + VISIT_LIFETIME);
    setcookie("visit_count", $visit_count, time() + 86400 * 365);
} else if ($visit_duration >= VISIT_LIFETIME / 2) {
    // Продлить записанное время посещения, если прошла половина VISIT_LIFETIME
    setcookie("visit_current", time() + VISIT_LIFETIME);
}
```

Код не тестировался, может содержать опечатки.
Требует PHP5.3+ из-за сокращенной формы тренарного оператора («`?:`»). Длинно: `... = isset($...) ? intval($...) : 0;`

Comment: как же глаза режет этот символ **@**